# Request for a date

Tags: r, date, calendar

I have a code that produces a report. In the beginning of the code I need ask for two dates (begin and and of period). How can a I do this?

I'm using `readline()`, but it's ugly

```
data1 <- as.Date(readline('Digite a data de inicio (dd/mm/aaaa): '), "%d/%m/%Y")
data2 <- readline('Digite a data de fim (não irá incluir o dia. Deixe em branco para pegar exatamente 1 mês contando da data de inicio): ')
```

I searched for some solution with a interactive GUI calendar, but I didn't found any.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Use a reproducible example or give at least the goal (output) you want.

Comment: I suppose you could build something using **gWidgets**, but that seems like it might be a lot of work for something this simple.

Comment: I just want a way to ask the two dates (`data1` and `data2`) without have to type it (a point-and-click system)

Comment: @joran There is `gcalendar` but it's not great, at least with Tcl/Tk